# How long will it take to validate a fix to a "500 Server Error" in Google Search Console?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, http-code-500, validation, coverage

I opened site (made with Wix) on the 25th August, and submitted sitemap in Google Search console.  Then I got the Server error (5xx) in coverage reporting:
[image: google search console Server error]

on the 29th August, my website has no other server errors, perhaps the error in side of Wix, I guess.
I started validation in search console, but yet validation status is 'started'.

My site has not so many pages, about 100 pages.
How many days it will take to validate this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure how long it will take, but I wouldn't worry too much about it.   At worst Google won't index that one page for a while.  It won't effect the rest of your site.

Comment: As Stephen says, it's a common situation with Google. If currently such pages work, they will back again shortly.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller "that one page ..." - the screenshot shows that 71 pages were affected, so that's probably the _entire site_.

Comment: If the pages are important and showing 500, I think you need to worry about that. Your highly driving traffic pages showing 500, needs to be fixed using redirection or you need to check your log files for the issues. Referring to a post which could be helpful, https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61514/should-i-remove-url-for-500-errors
Just check that REAL files are not returning this status (eg if some have javascript /css files etc USED by pages hosted in these folders!)

Comment: I've seen it take Google a couple 7-14 days to show some of these updates.  If the pages are working, I'm not sure that you need to panic or do anything more than verify that Google can reach your files currently.

Answer (score -2):

40 to 50 days this issue is resolved you wait minimum 45 days after this fix this error long time google

Comment: Such a short answer is not high quality. The amount of time you say sounds plausible but it would be much better if you could share how you know this. Do you have a reference? Do you have a personal experience?